# RDLC - Report : Repeat table multiple times

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am designing a rdlc report in vs2008 for windows application. I want to display the purchase and sales based on department. If i select one department it works fine but have no idea about how to  display each department's purchase and sales data in different tables. I have used embedded resource to the report. Report is designed based on the DataTable(on dataset - xsd file) and which contains, ITEMS,Purchase,Sales and Net as Fields. I have attached an image with describes the format that i want to display. [image]

Please provide me some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to add the Department field to your `DataTable`. Then in the RDLC add a `List` object to the body of the report. In the details section of the `List` have it use `Fields!Department.Value`. Finally, embedded the `Table` objects as-is into the `List`. You will now get one table per department.

Comment: Thanks for your response Biran. I am adding Department in the DataTable but still i have no idea with the report. Single DataTable will store all the record and provide to report once? Can you please explore more on it.

Answer (score 0):

I too needed a solution to repeat tables (functioning as a reportGroup) and your answer here helped lead me to a solution. There were additional needs: need to show each table on a separate page.

I am using fyiReporting Designer (project is dead) and was able to achieve this by creating a List, and then adding each of my 3 tables to the list, with each table set to page break at the end. I used the same grouping field/expression for the List and for each of the 3 tables.

Hope this helps folks in the future with similar challenges.

Comment: First line makes it seem like it's a 'me too' comment, but read further, and you will see this is actually an answer.